# [21000][1242] Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

Вот так выглядит мой запрос SQL:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT " +
                "q.id, " +
                "q.title, " +
                "q.user.fullName, " +
                "q.user.reputationCount, " +
                "q.viewCount, " +
                "q.countValuable, " +
                "q.persistDateTime,  " +
                "t.id, " +
                "t.name, " +
                "t.description, " +
                "(SELECT COUNT (a) FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id), " +
                "(SELECT a.isHelpful FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id) " +
                "FROM Question q JOIN q.tags t")
```

Методом исключений определил что ошибка вылетает на этой строке:

```
"(SELECT a.isHelpful FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id) "
```

Пишет - [21000][1242] Subquery returns more than 1 row, гуглим что только можно, разные решения уже есть, но все очень индивидуально, что не так в этой строке?

Comment: Subquery returns more than 1 row, какое слово непонятно?

Comment: слова то прекрасно понятны, как решить то?

Comment: Переделать запрос так, чтобы он возвращал не более чем 1 row, разумеется

Comment: да это логично, просто не понятно почему он возвращает более 1 row если запрос идет конкретно по Id

Comment: Выполните подзапрос отдельно и посмотрите почему

Comment: Одному вопросу соответствует несколько ответов, не иначе... впрочем, если с этим справитесь, стопудово уткнётесь в *FROM Question q JOIN **q.tags** t* - нет такой таблицы...

Comment: еще раз - все работает, таблицы все есть, косяк только со строкой которую я указал выше, и он почему то выбрасывает все значения, не взирая на то что я явно их связал в запросе

Comment: @AlexMartynets вы уже проверили подзапрос отдельно?

Comment: да, он выдает кучу строк, которые мне не нужны понятное дело

Comment: возможно мне не использовать subquery?

Comment: Сформулируйте для начала задачу. Что именно должен возвращать этот запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-то пригодится - я нашел такое решение, сильно голову конечно пришлось поломать, надеюсь кому-то упростит это жизнь:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT " +
                "q.id, " +
                "q.title, " +
                "q.user.fullName, " +
                "q.user.reputationCount, " +
                "q.viewCount, " +
                "q.countValuable, " +
                "q.persistDateTime,  " +
                "t.id, " +
                "t.name, " +
                "t.description, " +
                "(SELECT COUNT (a) FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id), " +
                "(SELECT CASE WHEN MAX (a.isHelpful) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id) " +
                "FROM Question q JOIN q.tags t")
```

Comment: Не надо писать в заголовке вопроса "решено". Если вопрос решен - отметьте галочкой ответ, являющийся решением.

Comment: ок, исправлю сейчас, уже, вижу :)

Answer (score 0):

если вам всё равно, какое из нескольких значений, что вернёт подзапрос, использовать - можно добавить в него 
`(SELECT a.isHelpful FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id limit 1)`, если это значение можно подогнать под 1 сортировками, то `order by a.isHelpful desc` или не `desc`

возвращает подзапрос несколько значений потому что в Answer есть несколько a.question.id равных q.id и подозреваю, что вы об этом знаете, раз делаете вот это - `(SELECT COUNT (a) FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id)` иначе эта вставка бессмысленна, так как если второй подзапрос должен возвращать один результат, то и этот всегда будет возвращать 1.

так же можно использовать  так, чтобы понять больше (так несколько значений склеятся в одно и результат по любому будет 1, но склеен из нескольких подходящих) -

```
SELECT group_concat(a.isHelpful) FROM Answer a WHERE a.question.id = q.id
```